# Difference between with and run in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Do `with` and `run` have the same functionality with only different syntax, or is there any major differences between `with` and `run`?

Which is the proper way?

```
adapter.run {
    notifyDataSetChanged()
    if (activityDetails.isEmpty())
        emptyText.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    else 
       emptyText.visibility = View.GONE
}


with(adapter){
   notifyDataSetChanged()
   if (activityDetails.isEmpty())
       emptyText.visibility = View.VISIBLE
   else 
       emptyText.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

Comment: `run{}` can do the chain call which is good for `null` check; `with{}` cannot. That's it.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

They have only syntactic difference, `run` is an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions) while `with` is not. Here are the definitions (in `kotlin-sdlib:1.0.3`):

```
public inline fun <T, R> T.run(block: T.() -> R): R = block() // equivalent to this.block()

public inline fun <T, R> with(receiver: T, block: T.() -> R): R = receiver.block()
```

Since `run` is an extension function, it has one more implicit argument of type `T`, so the argument types are the same. The bodies of the functions are also effectively the same.

Their performance should also be equivalent since both are [`inline` functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html): the resulting bytecode should only contain the inlined `block` body.

---

The differences in the functions usage are all caused by the fact that `run` is an extension.

First, `run` is suitable for calls chaining:

```
foo.run { bar }.run { baz }
```

Second, and more important, if a declared variable type has `run` function with the same signature, it will be called instead of the extension. And `run` can be shadowed by another extension. This is [how extensions are resolved](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extensions-are-resolved-statically). Example:

```
class MyClass {
     fun <R> run(blockIgnored: MyClass.() -> R): Nothing = throw RuntimeException()
}

"abcdefg".run { println("x") } // prints "x"
MyClass().run { println("x") } // throws RuntimeException
(MyClass() as Any).run { println("x") } // prints "x"
```

Comment: So i can user either. Dose both have any influence on performance of the application ?

Comment: @SaiKiran, yes, they are completely interchangeable, and their performance should be the same since they are both `inline` functions.

Comment: "We recommend with for calling functions on the context object without providing the lambda result."  https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html#with

Answer (score 19):

In normal case, they are pretty similar, but for a nullable variable, it's better to use `T.run()`

E.g. if `webview.settings` is nullable, below would show the distinct

```
with(webview.settings) {
    this?.javaScriptEnabled = true
    this?.databaseEnabled = true
}

// similarly
webview.settings?.run {
    javaScriptEnabled = true
    databaseEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: I guess it is even better to use "apply" in this scenario

Comment: Ya, but this is to answer the question of `with` vs `run`. As of when to use which, perhaps this article would help. https://medium.com/@elye.project/mastering-kotlin-standard-functions-run-with-let-also-and-apply-9cd334b0ef84

Comment: the return from the scope function is not used.  would you please explain why is it better using "apply" in this case?

Comment: @sean I would not use apply in this case because as you said nothing is being returned.