# Reasonable situations to use Kotlin's `let`

Tags: android, kotlin

In Kotlin, it's common to use `let` to execute code if an object (`let` receiver) isn't `null`, as an alternative to an `if != null` check, as in the following:

```
val nullable: String? = "anything"
nullable?.let {
    println(it)
}
```

In what other situations does it make sense to make use of `let`?

FYI, `let` is part of Kotlin's stdlib and is defined as follows:

```
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun <T, R> T.let(block: (T) -> R): R = block(this)
```

Comment: There is an open style guide issue for this at https://github.com/yole/kotlin-style-guide/issues/35.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Example of when should we use run, let, apply, also and with on Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45977011/example-of-when-should-we-use-run-let-apply-also-and-with-on-kotlin)

Comment: The referred question doesn't really give alternative ways to use it, which is what I was asking for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen `let` used to scope nested variables (ignoring `let`'s return):

```
    some.nested.foo.bar.let { bar -> 
        doSomething(bar)
        doMoreStuff(bar)
    }
```

It can be nice since it replaces the need to define a local variable, but I'm not sure how useful it actually is.

Could also be done with `apply`, though the readability is a bit worse, (`this` instead of `bar` in the scope).

Comment: So basically for shortening the var name?

Answer (score 2):

`let` is also useful when you work with `var` variables which are nullable.
For instance, we have this code

```
fun doSomething(value: String) {

}

class A {
    var boo: String? = null
    fun b() {
        if (boo != null) {
            doSomething(boo)
        }
    }
}
```

There, we have compile-time error inside `if` block because `boo` can be changed outside. To fix that we should either create a `val` variable

```
class A {
    var boo: String? = null
    fun b() {
        val b = boo
        if (b != null) {
            doSomething(b)
        }
    }
}
```

or use `let`

```
class A {
    var boo: String? = null
    fun b() {
        boo?.let {
            doSomething(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not make sense to me; why not just do  ``boo?.length`` then? `let` is redundant

Comment: @s1m0nw1 In this case, you are right. But I tried to show a case when you need not null variable.

Comment: @s1m0nw1 I've changed example

Comment: So know we're back to what I already suggested in the question itself, right? That's independent of `var`.

Comment: @s1m0nw1 yes, you are right. It doesn't matter use either `if` or `let` with `val` but if you use `var` and `if` you have to declare a `val` variable

Answer (score 0):

### scoping capabilities

The stdlib function `let` enables you to **confine a variable's scope** to a specific block of code. Shown here:

```
compile("a:b:c")
"io.vertx:vertx".let { v->
    compile("$v-lang-kotlin:$vertxVersion")
    compile("$v-lang-kotlin-coroutines:$vertxVersion")
} 
compile("x:y:z")
```

We could alternatively define a `val v: String = "io.vertx:vertx"` which might make the code more readable since that's what we'd do in Java for example. Yet, that `val` would be accessible throughout the whole method. We just want to have it available for the `compile` units with *vertx* involved, thus we confine the variable holding `io.vertx:vertx` to the `let` block.

Informations on the different scoping function alternatives can be found in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48218400/scope-functions-apply-with-run-also-let-where-do-the-names-come-from).

Answer (score 0):

you can use let in let in let by naming

```
someMethodCall()?.let{ nameOne ->
       // ....
       // some code here
       // ....
       val resultCall = nameOne
       someMethod2Call()?.let { -> nameTwo
          // ...
          val myVariable = nameTwo + resultCall
          // ... 
      }
}
```